# SFDX: How to refresh existent sandbox via CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox, sandbox-refresh

In sfdx guide there is a chapter named "**Create, Clone, or Delete a Sandbox**" (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_create_clone_sandboxes.htm).

But the problem we are facing now is how to refresh existent sandbox using sfdx cli.

It seems like there is no sfdx cli command/option to handle this, which is weird.

Are we missing something? If not, how then to trigger sandbox refresh in automatic way from CI/CD?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a command for it, as you noted. There was a [feature request](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/207) for this in 2019 and it was mentioned as a limitation back in [Summer '20](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/07/how-to-work-with-developer-sandboxes-and-the-salesforce-cli-part-1-of-2) and that it was on the roadmap. However, it is still not available (and unclear if it is still on the roadmap). You can see all the [available org commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm) and none include a refresh option.

> **As of Summer ‘20, the CLI sandbox refresh command is still on our roadmap, so you’ll need to use clicks in the production org or the Tooling API for now**. If you’re interested in the API option, it turns out that we recently shared a [Salesforce API collection for Postman](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/03/explore-the-salesforce-apis-with-a-postman-collection.html) that lets you run a sandbox refresh request with a few clicks.

You could look to leverage the Tooling API as it notes - but, I'll point out that there's a sfdx plugin, [sfpowerkit](https://github.com/dxatscale/sfpowerkit#sfpowerkitorgsandboxrefresh), that does have a command to refresh sandboxes as well.

`sfpowerkit:org:sandbox:refresh`

Answer (score 1):

Now It's possible to refresh a sandbox using the sf cli.

```
sf org refresh sandbox --name devSbx1 --target-org prodOrg
```

For more info please check this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_org_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_org_refresh_sandbox_unified).